# NSURL has stopped working in app

Tags: ios, ios6.1

I have written an app that downloads and then scrapes data from an html file. The app has been working fine for months, but the last couple of days it has stopped.

Here is the code...

```
NSString* urlString = [@"http://easytide.ukho.gov.uk/EASYTIDE/EasyTide/ShowPrediction.aspx?PortID=" stringByAppendingString:portCode];
urlString = [urlString stringByAppendingString:@"&PredictionLength=7"];
NSURL* easyTidesUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData* easyTidesHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:easyTidesUrl];
```

When I examine the NSURL object, the url has not set properly (there is an error with the string) and the NSURL object is shown as . I know similar questions have been asked in the past (i have tried the solutions and they don't work in this instance), but it seems bizarre that the app was working fine and is now broken without doing anything to it!

---

Here is some more code... basically the part that has stopped working is the first part of the function...

```
+(void)getTides:(NSMutableArray *)tidalDateArray withPortCode:(NSString*)portCode
{
    NSString *parameter = [portCode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://easytide.ukho.gov.uk/EASYTIDE/EasyTide/ShowPrediction.aspx?PortID=%@&PredictionLength=7", parameter];
    NSURL *easyTidesUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *easyTidesHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:easyTidesUrl];

    TFHpple* tidesParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:easyTidesHtmlData];

    NSString* easyTidesXPathQueryString = @"//div[@class='HWLWPanel']/table/tr/th[@class='HWLWTableHeaderCell']";
    NSArray* tideDateNodes = [tidesParser searchWithXPathQuery:easyTidesXPathQueryString];

    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                          initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

Comment: are you getting NSURL *easyTidesUrl nil ?

Comment: No, the NSURL object has a memory address etc. so i assume it is initialised... the problem seems to be with the nsurl.urlString

Comment: I tried the above address and was redirected to an error page... If you have not amended the app and it breaks for no reason, then the problem could be somewhere else. I suspect there may be changes in the website or host server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably some illegal charter in the `portCode` variable, like a space:

```
NSString *parameter = [portCode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://easytide.ukho.gov.uk/EASYTIDE/EasyTide/ShowPrediction.aspx?PortID=%@&PredictionLength=7", parameter];
NSURL *easyTidesUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *easyTidesHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:easyTidesUrl];
```

Comment: the url has no spaces, but the actual string in urlString object is showing up as an unknown class... the url is:http://www.ukho.gov.uk/easytide/EasyTide/ShowPrediction.aspx?PortID=0131&PredictionLength=7

Comment: Did you give my code a try, it should filter out some unsupported charters in you `startViewController` variable.

Comment: I did try it... creating the safer parameter variable from portCode made no difference unfortunately...

Comment: Can you give an example of the `portCode` variable, also if you can use `po` to print out the `easyTidesUrl`.

Comment: Printing description of portCode:
0131

Printing description of easyTidesUrl:
http://easytide.ukho.gov.uk/EASYTIDE/EasyTide/ShowPrediction.aspx?PortID=0131&PredictionLength=7

fr some reason there is an extra EasyTide in this url... it isn't there in xcode...

Comment: The the issue is somewhere else, I just tried with 0131 in my code example and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Easytide seems to be down so might not be an API problem!

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like it was a very simple one after all... The url itself was wrong - whether they changed it or whether it got changed in the code I don't know... Thank you for all your help though and code improvements...